# Can there be a homomorphism from $Z_4 ⊕Z_4$ onto $Z_8?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can there be a homomorphism from $Z_4 ⊕Z_4$ onto $Z_8?$

**Attempt**

Suppose $\psi :Z_4 ⊕Z_4 \rightarrow Z_8$ is a homomorphism

Then $|\ker \psi| = \dfrac {16}{8}=2$.

If $\psi (a,b) = c,$ then $O(c)$ divides $8$.

Please tell me how do I proceed now?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If such a homomorphism exists, it must be that some $x\in \Bbb Z_4\oplus\Bbb Z_4$ maps to a generator in $\Bbb Z_8$. But the order of the image divides the order of the initial element, i.e. $o(\psi(a))\big|o(a)\big|4$, hence no image can have order $8$, and so no such homomorphism exists.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It struck me, but I lost it there :)